# NotifyIcon balloon wrong application icon

Tags: c#, wpf

I changed the icon in my WPF application, and the new icon is shown everywhere except in the notify icon balloon.

I'm using the System.Windows.Forms Notify Icon. I've set the icon to the new icon, and it shows in the actual notify icon, in the taskbar. But when I show a balloon, the application icon (at the top of the balloon, in Windows 11) shows the old icon.

I've removed the old icon from the project, I've changed the application icon in the project properties. But the old icon keeps showing in the balloon.

Anyone know why this is, and where it's getting the icon from?

```
this._notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
this._notifyIcon.Text = "Application Name";
this._notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconPath);
this._notifyIcon.ContextMenu = contextMenu;

this._notifyIcon.Visible = true;


this._notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(timeout, title, message, ToolTipIcon.None);
```

Comment: Have you verified that `iconPath` points to the expected location while debugging?

Comment: Yeah, it's in the application folder. And I added a File.Exists check, definitely the right icon
Edit: Also tried changing to another icon (for testing), the taskbar icon updates but the balloon still shows the old one

Comment: Google "reset shell icon cache" to possibly get ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this issue, I couldn't work out what was going on. But gave up using the System.Windows.Forms NotifyIcon, and used [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf/).

It works almost the same, so was easy to switch and shows the correct icon.